# With the serialize field, how to manage updates w/o replacing everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, serialization

In my user model, I have a guided field that is set to serialize. By default the field is nil but the plan is for it to end up like this later on:

```
{
guided_step1 : true,
guided_step1_decision : 33,
guided_step2 : true,
guided_step3 : false,
guided_step4 : false
}
```

My question is, if I want to post to the server param[:user][:guided_step3] = true, that ends up deleting everything else. How can I post and just update the field or insert it? What's the right way to handle this use case? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential approaches here. The simplest is to merge hashes in your controller instead of just sending them to `update_attributes`:

```rb
guided_steps = params[:user].delete(:guided_steps) || {}
@user.guided_steps = (@user.guided_steps || {}).merge(guided_steps)
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Another, if you really want it to be automatic, is to redefine the writer method for `guided_steps` in your `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def guided_steps=(new_steps)
    gs = self.guided_steps || {}
    gs = gs.merge(new_steps || {})
    write_attribute(:guided_steps, gs)
  end
  ...
end
```

This should make so that when you call `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` in your controller, the new `guided_steps` will be merged with the old ones. One potential downside to this approach is that `guided_steps=` will work a little less intuitively than before. For example, `@user.guided_steps = {}` will not clear the hash. So it's up to you to balance the pros and cons of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why this does not work?

```
user = User.find id

user.datastpeps[:guided_step3] = true
user.save
```

Comment: well that would work but then I need to hard code everything. I'm interested in using a jQuery ajax post to post the params and have rails do it's magic to make the updates

Comment: So the only way is that jquery sends the full hash and not only the new pairs, and you have to rely on it, for example if same user do that 2 times in same instant, something will be lost and data will be inconsistent.